Dash Ag-Grid table, I want to add the ... button to each cell on click the cell, the cell should expanded show full text in the cell
I created an Dash-App, I have a Dash ag-grid table and some column have too much text. Can I do abstracted the text with ... button in ag-grid table. On click the ... button then user seen full text. As can seen in the image, summarised description there so much text can optimizer by only show 50 characters or 100 characters. When the user find the text helpful, then show the full text in data cell.
I try to find some solution which use the cell rendering in dash ag-grid. But cannot make it work.enter image description here
window.dashAgGridComponentFunctions = window.dashAgGridComponentFunctions || {};
 
class TruncatedTextCell {
    init(params) {
        // Store the params
        this.params = params;
        // Create the cell wrapper element
        this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
        this.eGui.className = 'truncated-cell';
        this.maxLength = 100;
        this.isExpanded = false;
        this.render();
    }
 
    getGui() {
        return this.eGui;
    }
 
    render() {
        // Safely access the value from params
        const text = this.params && this.params.value ? String(this.params.value) : '';
        // Only truncate if we have text longer than maxLength
        const truncatedText = text.length > this.maxLength 
            ? text.substring(0, this.maxLength) + '...'
            : text;
 
        if (this.isExpanded) {
            this.eGui.innerHTML = `
<div style="position: relative; padding: 8px;">
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;">
                        ${this.escapeHtml(text)}
</div>
<button 
                        style="position: absolute; top: 8px; right: 8px; padding: 4px 8px; 
                               font-size: 12px; background-color: #3b82f6; color: white; 
                               border-radius: 4px; border: none; cursor: pointer;"
                        class="show-less-btn">
                        Show Less
</button>
</div>
            `;
 
            const showLessBtn = this.eGui.querySelector('.show-less-btn');
            showLessBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                this.isExpanded = false;
                this.render();
            });
        } else {
            this.eGui.innerHTML = `
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; gap: 8px; padding: 4px;">
<span style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                        ${this.escapeHtml(truncatedText)}
</span>
                    ${text.length > this.maxLength ? `
<button 
                            style="padding: 4px 8px; font-size: 12px; background-color: #3b82f6; 
                                   color: white; border-radius: 4px; border: none; cursor: pointer;
                                   flex-shrink: 0;"
                            class="expand-btn">
                            ...
</button>
                    ` : ''}
</div>
            `;
 
            const expandBtn = this.eGui.querySelector('.expand-btn');
            if (expandBtn) {
                expandBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    this.isExpanded = true;
                    this.render();
                });
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Helper function to escape HTML and prevent XSS
    escapeHtml(unsafe) {
        return unsafe
            .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
            .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
            .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
            .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
            .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
    }
 
    refresh(params) {
        this.params = params;
        this.render();
        return true;
    }
 
    destroy() {
        // Cleanup if needed
    }
}
 
// Create the component function that returns a new instance
window.dashAgGridComponentFunctions.TruncatedTextCell = (params) => {
    const component = new TruncatedTextCell();
    component.init(params);
    return component;
};

columnDefs = [
        {'field': 'Patent ID'}, 
        {'field': 'Title'}, 
        {'field': 'Abstract'}, 
        {
            
            "field": "Summarised Description",
            "cellRenderer": "TruncatedTextCell",
            "width": 400,
            "autoHeight": True
            
        }, 
        {'field': 'Family'}, 
        {'field': 'Country Code'}, 
        {'field': 'Organization'}, 
        {'field': 'DA'}, 
        {'field': 'Publication Date'}, 
        {'field': 'Priority Date'}

